Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource
I'm currently following a guide to set up Spring Security for my application, I don't fully understand what's going on with the code so it's a bit hard to debug.
The methods that are deprecated are: cors, jwt, csrf, and oauth2ResourceServer.
How should I go about replacing these, I used GPT and got some code but ended up with a error saying:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/luv2code/spring_boot_letstalk/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.luv2code.spring_boot_letstalk.SpringBootLetstalkApplication.main(SpringBootLetstalkApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/luv2code/spring_boot_letstalk/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1543) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1511) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1392) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:887) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta.authenticationEntryPoint(Okta.java:133) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(Okta.java:81) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at com.luv2code.spring_boot_letstalk.config.SecurityConfiguration.filterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.luv2code.spring_boot_letstalk.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.luv2code.spring_boot_letstalk.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at com.luv2code.spring_boot_letstalk.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

Here's the code below:
package com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.config;

import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable Cross Site Request Forgery
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Protect endpoints at /api/<type>/secure
        http.authorizeRequests(configurer ->
                configurer
                        .antMatchers("/api/books/secure/**",
                                "/api/reviews/secure/**",
                                "/api/messages/secure/**",
                                "/api/admin/secure/**")
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        // Add CORS filters
        http.cors();

        // Add content negotiation strategy
        http.setSharedObject(ContentNegotiationStrategy.class,
                new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());

        // Force a non-empty response body for 401's to make the response friendly
        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);

        return http.build();
    }

}


Here are my dependencies:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I have the proper oauth2 information (client id, issuer) set up in my application.properties so I don't think that's the issue.
Thanks
I tried to setup Spring security, used GPT and gave me code with a bunch of new methods and things that seemed overly complicated to make it work. Resulted in the same error as above. Also tried replacing with http.getOrBuild() as others have suggested, but got nowhere.

How comes that you are working with servlets from javax in a n new application? Pick recent JDK & Spring version and work with servlet from jakarta. For maybe more up to date tutorials, go there https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2
